# Add N business days to a given date skipping holidays, exceptions and weekends in SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm facing a challenging task here, spent a day on it and **I was only able to solve it through a procedure** but it is taking too long to run for all projects.

I would like to solve it in a single query if possible (no functions or procedures).

There is already some questions here doing it in programming languages OR sql functions/procedures (Wich I also solved min). So I'm asking if it is possible to solve it with just SQL

The background info is:

- A `project` table
- A `phase` table
- A `holiday` table
- A `dayexception` table which cancel a holiday or a weekend day (make that date as a working day) and it is associated with a project
- A project may have 0-N phases
- A phase have a `start date`, a `duration` and a `draworder` (needed by the system)
- Working days is all days that is not weekend days and not a holiday (exception is if that date is in `dayexception` table)

Consider this following scenario:

```
project |           phase(s)                        |  Dayexception     |  Holiday
  id    | id   pid    start     duration  draworder | pid       date    |   date
   1    | 1     1   2014-01-20     10         0     |  1     2014-01-25 | 2014-01-25
        | 2     1   2014-02-17     14         2     |                   |
```

The `ENDDATE` for the `project id 1` and `phase id 1` is actually `2014-01-31` see the generated data below:
The date on the below data (and now on) is formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy` (Brazil format) and the value `N` is `null`

```
proj  pha     start          day      weekday  dayexcp      holiday  workday
 1     1    20/01/2014    20/01/2014     2        N            N        1
 1     1    20/01/2014    21/01/2014     3        N            N        1
 1     1    20/01/2014    22/01/2014     4        N            N        1
 1     1    20/01/2014    23/01/2014     5        N            N        1
 1     1    20/01/2014    24/01/2014     6        N            N        1
 1     1    20/01/2014    25/01/2014     7    25/01/2014   25/01/2014   1
 1     1    20/01/2014    26/01/2014     1        N            N        0
 1     1    20/01/2014    27/01/2014     2        N        27/01/2014   0
 1     1    20/01/2014    28/01/2014     3        N            N        1
 1     1    20/01/2014    29/01/2014     4        N            N        1
```

To generate the above data I created a view `daysOfYear` with all days from 2014 and 2015 (it can be bigger or smaller, created it with two years for the year turn cases) with a CTE query if you guys want to see it let me know and I will add it here. And the following select statement:

```
select ph.project_id proj, 
       ph.id phase_id pha,
       ph.start,
       dy.curday day,
       dy.weekday, /*weekday here is a calling to the weekday function of db2*/
       doe.exceptiondate dayexcp,
       h.date holiday,
       case when exceptiondate is not null or (weekday not in (1,7) and h.date is null)
            then 1 else 0 end as workday
  from phase ph
       inner join daysofyear dy
          on (year(ph.start) = dy.year)
       left join dayexception doe
          on (ph.project_id = doe.project_id
              and dy.curday = truncate(doe.exceptiondate))
       left join holiday h
          on (dy.curday = truncate(h.date))
 where ph.project_id = 1
   and ph.id = 1
   and dy.year in (year(ph.start),year(ph.start)+1)
   and dy.curday>=ph.start
   and dy.curday<=ph.start + ((duration - 1) days)
   order by ph.project_id, start, dy.curday, draworder
```

To solve this scenario I created the following query:

```
select project_id, 
       min(start), 
       max(day) + sum(case when workday=0 then 1 else 0 end) days as enddate
  from project_phase_days /*(view to the above select)*/
```

This will return correctly:

```
proj     start           enddate
 1     20/01/2014      31/01/2014
```

The problem I couldn't solve is if the days I'm adding (non workdays `sum(case when workday=0 then 1 else 0 end) days` ) to the last enddate (`max(day)`) is weekend days or holidays or exceptions.

See the following scenario (**The duration for the below phase is 7**):

```
proj   pha     start          day      weekday  dayexcp   holiday  workday
 81    578    14/04/2014    14/04/2014     2        N        N        1
 81    578    14/04/2014    15/04/2014     3        N        N        1
 81    578    14/04/2014    16/04/2014     4        N        N        1
 81    578    14/04/2014    17/04/2014     5        N        N        1
 81    578    14/04/2014    18/04/2014     6        N    18/04/2014   0
 81    578    14/04/2014    19/04/2014     7        N                 0
 81    578    14/04/2014    20/04/2014     1        N    20/04/2014   0
           /*the below data I added to show the problem*/              
 81    578    14/04/2014    21/04/2014     2        N    21/04/2014   0
 81    578    14/04/2014    22/04/2014     3        N                 1
 81    578    14/04/2014    23/04/2014     4        N                 1
 81    578    14/04/2014    24/04/2014     5        N                 1
```

With the above data my query will return

```
proj     start       enddate
 81    14/04/2014   23/04/2014
```

But the correct result would be the `enddate` as `24/04/2014` that's because my query doesn't take into account if the days after the last day is weekend days or holidays (or exceptions for that matter) as you can see in the dataset above the day `21/04/2014` which is outside my duration is also a Holiday.

I also tried to create a CTE on `phase` table to add a day for each iteration until the duration is over but I couldn't add the `exceptions` nor the `holidays` because the DB2 won't let me add a left join on the CTE recursion. Like this:

```
 with CTE (projectid, start, enddate, duration, level) as (
     select projectid, start, start as enddate, duration, 1
       from phase 
      where project_id=1
        and phase_id=1
      UNION ALL
     select projectid, start, enddate + (level days), duration, 
            case when isWorkDay(enddate + (level days)) then level+1 else level end as level
       from CTE left join dayexception on ...
                left join holiday on ...
      where level < duration
 ) select * from CTE
```

PS: the above query doesn't work because of the DB2 limitations and `isWorkDay` is just as example (it would be a case on the dayexception and holiday table values).

If you have any doubts, please just ask in the comments.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to count business days forward and backwards.**

Background last Century I worked at this company that used this technique.  So this is a pseudo code answer.  It worked great for their purposes.

What you need is a table that contains a date column and and id column that increments by one.  Fill the table with only business dates...  That's the tricky part because of the observing date on another date.  Like 2017-01-02 was a holiday where I work but its not really a recognized holiday AFAIK.

How to get 200 business days in the future.

1. Select the min(id) where date >= to current date.
2. Select the date where id=id+200.

How to get 200 business days in the past.

1. Select the min(id) from table with a date >= to current date.
2. Select the date with id=id-200.

Business days between.

```
select count(*) from myBusinessDays where "date" between startdate and enddate
```

Good Luck as this is pseudo code.

Comment: It is actually a pretty good idea. There is no need for the `ID` column though, one can use the `ROW_NUMBER`, `ROWID` or something like it depending on the RDBMs. The Idea that I like is to have a table/view with the working days. I can generate that excluding/adding the non working days or exceptions. Thank you. I will try that on Monday when I get back to work and I will share this experience. +1

Comment: Row number if you can keep it straight through scope creep minutia. 

Comment: Hi there @danny117. I've added my final solution, I will mark your answer as correct one as it gave the central idea to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So, using the idea of @danny117 answer I was able to create a query to solve my problem. Not exactly his idea but it gave me directions to solve it, so I will mark it as the correct answer and this answer is to share the actual code to solve it.

First let me share the view I created to the periods. As I said I created a `view` `daysofyear` with the data of 2014 and 2015 (in my final solution I added a considerable bigger interval without impacting in the end result). Ps: the date format here is in Brazil format `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
 create or replace view daysofyear as 
 with CTE (curday, year, weekday) as (
      select a1.firstday, year(a1.firstday), dayofweek(a1.firstday)
        from (select to_date('01/01/1990', 'dd/mm/yyyy') firstday 
                from sysibm.sysdummy1) as a1
      union all
      select a.curday + 1 day as sumday, 
             year(a.curday + 1 day), 
             dayofweek(a.curday + 1 day)
        from CTE a
       where a.curday < to_date('31/12/2050', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
 )
 select * from cte;
```

With that View I then created another view with the query on my question adding an amount of days based on my historical data (bigger phase + a considerable margin) here it is:

```
create or replace view project_phase_days as
select ph.project_id proj, 
       ph.id phase_id pha,
       ph.start,
       dy.curday day,
       dy.weekday, /*weekday here is a calling to the weekday function of db2*/
       doe.exceptiondate dayexcp,
       h.date holiday,
       ph.duration,
       case when exceptiondate is not null or (weekday not in (1,7) and h.date is null)
            then 1 else 0 end as workday
  from phase ph
       inner join daysofyear dy
          on (year(ph.start) = dy.year)
       left join dayexception doe
          on (ph.project_id = doe.project_id
              and dy.curday = truncate(doe.exceptiondate))
       left join holiday h
          on (dy.curday = truncate(h.date))
 where dy.year in (year(ph.start),year(ph.start)+1)
   and dy.curday>=ph.start
   and dy.curday<=ph.start + ((duration - 1) days) + 200 days 
                                            /*max duration in database is 110*/
```

After that I then created this query:

```
select p.id,
       a.start,
       a.curday as enddate
  from project p left join
       (
        select p1.project_id,
               p1.duration,
               p1.start,
               p1.curday,
               row_number() over (partition by p1.project_id 
                                  order by p1.project_id, p1.start, p1.curday) rorder
          from project_phase_days p1
         where p1.validday=1
       ) as a
       on (p.id = a.project_id
          and a.rorder = a.duration)
order by p.id, a.start
```

What it does is select all workdays from my view (joined with my other days view) rownumber based on the `project_id` ordered by `project_id, start date and  current day (curday)` I then join with the `project table` to get the trick part that solved the problem which is `a.rorder = a.duration`

If you guys need more explanation I will be glad to provide.